# Http status error [301] in response Dio Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, dio

There is an api for authorization, I send a request using thunder client, everything seems to be ok, I get a token in response, but when I try to knock on the same link in the application itself using the dio library, I get an Http status error [301] in response, what could be the problem, I didn't really find an answer anywhere?

how do I send a request

```
final response = await _dio.post(
      'http://someaddress.com/api/auth/login',
      data: {"login": phone, "password": event.password},
    );
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: That probably means that in your thunder client you set a header used for authentication against the API, which you appear to not set in your dart code. If that is not the case, it could be that the API - for whatever reason - deems a request unauthorized when some standard header, like User-Agent, is not to its liking.

Answer (score 0):

Http 301 status code means that the link is not anymore available and new one is defined in `Location` header. The response looks like something like this.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://foo.bar/foobar
```

Response headers in `dio` can be accessed by [headers](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/Response/headers.html) property.